# inequality property of integrals

Tags: integration

Suppose $f(x), g(x), h(x)$ are non-negative real valued functions on $[a, b],\;\;(0\leq a<b)$ and $p$ is any positive real number and $f(x)^p \leq g(x)^p+ h(x)^p.$ Is it true that

$(\int_a^bf(x)dx)^p \leq (\int_a^bg(x)dx)^p+ (\int_a^bh(x)dx)^p?$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true. Let us start by consider the case when $g (x)=h (x)$, then we are in $ f^p (x)\le 2g^p (x) $ or $ f (x)\le 2^{1/p} g (x) $. Now, we need to show that $$(\int{f (x) dx})^p \le 2 (\int {g (x) dx})^p$$ and this is equivalent to write $$\int{f (x) dx}\le 2^{1/p} \int {g (x) dx}$$ which is true by assumptions (follows by property of integrals if $ r (t)< s (t)$ then $\int r (t) <\int  s(t) $).

Now, for the general case, we use the inequality $$ f^p (x)\le g^p (x)+h^p (x) \le 2\max\{{g^p (x), h^p (x)}\}.$$ WLOG,  assume $g\ge h $ for all $ x $ and all $ p $. Therefore by the previous part the results follows.

Comment: I think the assumption ' g≥h for all x and all p.'  looses the generality.